# How to protect a specific URL with HTTP authetication?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I know the procedure to protect a directory by using htaccess and htpasswd.But I want to protect a specific url like `domain.com/admin`?

Please Help!

Comment: What have you tried and why can't you protect /admin?  What is special about it?

Answer (score 0):

Just create an .htapsswd (maybe via [a generator](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/)), and add this to your .htaccess:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "My Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

As long as that .htaccess is on the same folder, everything in there will be protected by password.

Comment: I want to protect a URL not directory.

Comment: i found a solution.We have to use server configuration file for this.In my case i used 
apache configuration file and added following code there.

<LocationMatch /domain.com/admin>

My stuff
</LocationMatch>